# Input decimal numbers in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am extremely beginner in programming language. so i am facing some problems. please help me out.
Is it possible to take input a floating or double number with 2 digits after the decimal point using 'scanf' in C ??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Share some of your current code could help you to get help from this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: [How to only accept a certain precision (so many decimals places) in scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132748/how-to-only-accept-a-certain-precision-so-many-decimals-places-in-scanf)

```
float value;
scanf("%4f", &value);
```

It's not really do that, but reads 4 digit **edit: 4 characters** float number. You can set other number instead of 4.

If you really need only 2 decimal places you can read the number with `scanf`, and after that round it using `roundf`.

```
#include <math.h>
...
float value;
scanf("%f", &value);
value = roundf(value*100)/100
```

Comment: Minor: Using `round(value*100.0)/100`  (`round()` `100.0`) typically avoids range and precision issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can read floats with

```
float a;
scanf("%f", &a);
```

You can read doubles with

```
double a;
scanf("%lf", &a);
```